# Is there an Ampscript function that counts occurrence of a letter in a string?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'd like to read the total number of comma (,) in an incoming string.

Answer (score 3):

You could build a rowset using [BuildRowSetFromString()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/buildrowsetfromstring.htm) to test the number of commas:

```
%%[
  SET @rs = BuildRowSetFromString(myField,',')
  SET @rowCount = RowCount(@rs)
  VAR @commas
  IF @rowCount == 1 THEN 
    SET @commas = 0
  ELSE
    SET @commas = Subtract(@rowCount,1)
  ENDIF
]%%
Number of Commas: %%=v(@commas)=%%
```